# jqGrid: Problem with select-element

Tags: jqgrid

If the select element doesn't have any options the name of the select-list won't be rendered. As I fill the select automatically on one paritcular event I can not save the selected value because the select has no name. Is there a jqGrid-property to manage this?

Comment: Why you can have select element without any options? It seems to me easier to change your code which generate the select-contain as to try to make jqGrid working with empty selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have problem with cell editing and you created column in colModel something similar:

```
{name:'strType', index:'strType', width:70, sortable:false, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: "" }}
```

Everything you would like to know about this feature is written in [docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#select) and there is:

> The editoptions value must contain a set
>   of value

So I would set name attribute by myself. If you do something in javascript that add option to select box, setting name attribute is simple.

```
$('#1_strType').attr('name', 'strType')
```

I haven't tested yet this solution, but I assume that this could work :)